# Highcharts min and max xAxis

Tags: javascript, web, graph, highcharts

I have a problem with Hightcharts.

I want to display my graph in a complete day (between 08/12/2012 0:00 and 08/12/2012 23:59)

So I use the xAxis.min and xAxis.max of the Highcharts [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.min).

But when I display my graph I don't see the min and max value.

```
"ic": "images/ciblerouge.png",
"icTrack": "",
"color": "255,0,0,0.5",
"title": "skywaveUnitTest - 08/10/2012",
"xAxis": {
    "min": 1349661600000,
    "max": 1349747999000,
    "startOnTick": false
},
"aData": [{
    "name": "Vitesse (Km/h)",
    "data": [{
        "x": 1349711130233,
        "y": 10,
        "l": 16789
    },
    {
        "x": 1349711388379,
        "y": 10,
        "l": null
    },
    {
        "x": 1349711388380,
        "y": 290,
        "l": 16790
    },
    {
        "x": 1349711861797,
        "y": 290,
        "l": 16791
    },
    {
        "x": 1349717896097,
        "y": 290,
        "l": 16792
    },
    {
        "x": 1349718759813,
        "y": 290,
        "l": 16793
    },
    {
        "x": 1349719132107,
        "y": 290,
        "l": 16794
    }],
    "visible": true,
    "yAxis": 1,
    "marker": {
        "enabled": false,
        "radius": 0
    }
},
{
    "name": "Altitude",
    "data": [{
        "x": 1349711130233,
        "y": 0,
        "l": 16789
    },
    {
        "x": 1349711388379,
        "y": 0,
        "l": null
    },
    {
        "x": 1349711388380,
        "y": -800,
        "l": 16790
    },
    {
        "x": 1349711861797,
        "y": -800,
        "l": 16791
    },
    {
        "x": 1349717896096,
        "y": -800,
        "l": null
    },
    {
        "x": 1349717896097,
        "y": 0,
        "l": 16792
    },
    {
        "x": 1349718759812,
        "y": 0,
        "l": null
    },
    {
        "x": 1349718759813,
        "y": 2400,
        "l": 16793
    },
    {
        "x": 1349719132107,
        "y": 2400,
        "l": 16794
    }],
    "visible": false,
    "yAxis": 1,
    "marker": {
        "enabled": false,
        "radius": 0
    }
}],
```

Comment: Do you use any wrapper? Because in highcharts you need to use i.e series object instead od aData etc.

Comment: It's a little difficult because i make the json in a VB.net function and i return for my javascript.

Comment: Your issue is `aData`. That is not a valid highcharts property/object.

Comment: Thx four your help you have right.